# OTP Generation in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application, in that I have generated the OTP and sent to the user via mail. Now I want that this OTP should be active only for 5min after that it won’t work. How I can do this, please help.

Comment: Please refer how to ask a question. Please do a research and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: can you show the code for generating the `OTP` so accordingly we can check and make is inactive for the time asked

Answer (score -1):

You can append current datetime with that generated otp and Encrypt it.

So you can validate the OTP with that date time.
And when you receive a request using this OTP then decrypt and validate the OTP using that appended datetime.